# jquery mouseover event firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    $(function(){
    $('#webs').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#websitehov').fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $('#webs').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#websitehov').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

I know there are a ton of questions on this but I've tried a number of them and still not working, I've tried different event handlers including .hover, .mouseover and .mouseenter.
The image hover/hover out effect fires multiple times when it enters and whenever I move the mouse inside the image the two events start firing. 
I found one solution that stopped this :

```
(function(){
$('#webs').hover(function(){
$('#websitehov').fadeIn('slow')
}, function() { });
});
```

but this only worked for the hover in and not for hover out because the empty function was the mouseout event handler, idk if you can override this?

Comment: using **.hover() with a callback** will be a good solution.

Comment: tried and same result, still flashing multiple times and firing every time you move the mouse and continues to fire one more time once you leave the area  code:   

$(function(){
 $('#webs').hover(function(){
  $('#websitehov').fadeIn('slow');
 }, function(){
  $('#websitehov').fadeOut('slow');
 });
});

Comment: either craete a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or post more codes including html and css

Comment: i found the problem, the image that fires when hovering over the first image goes infront of the other image so they're fighting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible problem I can see is that of animation queuing, clear the animation queue before addition another one

```
$(function () {
    $('#webs').hover(function () {
        $('#websitehov').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function () {
        $('#websitehov').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X55rA/)