# Mouseenter called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website, and for the about page, I have pictures that I want to fade to 0.5 opacity and then have text fade in on top if them. My issue is that whenever I put my mouse over one of the images, it, and the text on top of it fades in and out multiple times. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/oLckb6h3/1/) a link to the section of my code I'm having trouble with. The issue only occurs if you're moving your mouse over the image from outside of the containing div.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fade').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(150, 0.5);
    $(this).siblings().fadeIn(150);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(150, 1);
    $(this).siblings().fadeOut(150);
});
});
```

I've noticed that when I remove the second line of code in both mouseenter and mouseleave that it resolves the issue. I've tried mouseover, hover, stopPropogation, I've looked through all of these:

[mouseenter event called twice even after stopPropagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888590/mouseenter-event-called-twice-even-after-stoppropagation)

[Mouseover and mouseleave trigger every time I move the mouse inside the given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080067/mouseover-and-mouseleave-trigger-every-time-i-move-the-mouse-inside-the-given-el)

[JS mouseenter triggered twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179191/js-mouseenter-triggered-twice)

[JQuery mouseover function firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163876/jquery-mouseover-function-firing-multiple-times)

[How to stop toggle event from being fired multiple times on mouseenter/mouseleave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605935/how-to-stop-toggle-event-from-being-fired-multiple-times-on-mouseenter-mouseleav)

[jquery mouseover event firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468456/jquery-mouseover-event-firing-twice)

[Jquery mouseenter() vs mouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286532/jquery-mouseenter-vs-mouseover)

and tried everything they suggested but so far nothing has worked for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is you are fading in the elements over the image which interferes with the mouseover listener. So when you hover over the image, it begins to fade, but when the elements fade in, then it blocks the cursor from the image and triggers a mouseout event then it repeats once the elements go away.

I think the quickest way to handle this is to give the container of the image the class of fade, that way the siblings don't interfere with the mouseover listener.

You could change the markup to:

```
<div id="image-wrapper" >
    <ul id="team-members">
        <li class="tile-wrapper fade">
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/158x210"/>
                <h3 class="bio bio-header" style="display:none;">Header</h3>
                <p class="bio bio-footer" style="display:none;">Information</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fade').mouseenter(function(ev) {
        $(this).fadeTo(150, 0.5);
        $(this).find('img').siblings().fadeIn(150);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(150, 1);
        $(this).find('img').siblings().fadeOut(150);
    });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLckb6h3/2/

Comment: is there any way to key the text that's overlayed from getting less opaque?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the elements positioning, you are trying to overlay the images sibling, which interferes with the hover event on the image. To fix this try calling the hover state on a parent such as the "tile" class, and editing the CSS to position the text over the image using z-index and positioning.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tile').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('img').fadeTo(150, 0.5).siblings().fadeIn(150);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children('img').fadeTo(150, 1).siblings().fadeOut(150);
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.bio {
    padding:15px;
}

.bio-header {
    margin-top:-150px;
}

.tile { display: inline-block;}

.tile > img { z-index: 0; position: relative; }

.tile > .bio { z-index: 1; position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-wrapper">
    <ul id="team-members">
        <li class="tile-wrapper">
            <div class="tile">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/158x210" class="fade" />
                <h3 class="bio bio-header" style="display:none;">Header</h3>
                <p class="bio bio-footer" style="display:none;">Information</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```